# RegionPlot not plotting some regions

Tags: plotting, regions

`RegionPlot` appears to have regressed in version 10.4

In 10.3.1

```
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y}]]
```

gives

[image]

But in 10.4 both

```
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y}]]
```

and

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

give

[image]

However, 10.4 knows that this is a valid region.

```
DiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y}]
```

[image]

Can anyone else confirm this?

Win 7 Pro 64 bit.

Comment: Same on linux, however `RegionPlot[0.99 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 1.01, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 200]` this works.

Comment: I sent product feedback to [Wolfram Tech Support](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback) on this issue.

Comment: This could just be a case of the function catching up with the documentation, as the help page for `RegionPlot` in both versions states "`RegionPlot` can in general only find regions of positive measure; it cannot find regions that are just lines or points"

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer but rather an extended comment demonstrating another aspect of the problem.

```
$Version

(*  "10.4.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (February 26, 2016)"  *)
```

If the region is given some thickness it is displayed:

```
Manipulate[RegionPlot[
  ImplicitRegion[1 - 10^(-n) <= x^2 + y^2 <= 1 + 10^(-n), {x, y}]], {{n, 7}, 
  Range[10], ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

[image]

However, when the thickness is made too small, another problem arises: the region displays as if it were a disk.

[image]