# RegionPlot not plotting BoundaryRegion

Tags: plotting, regions

This question is related to
[RegionPlot not plotting some regions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109225/regionplot-not-plotting-some-regions/109235#109235]).

I have the following region and want to plot the area and the boundary. In Mathematica 10.3.1 it works fine but not in 10.4.

```
reg = RegionDifference[Disk[{2, 0}, 2, {0, \[Pi]}],Disk[{1, 0}, 1, {0, \[Pi]}]];
{RegionPlot[reg, AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 250], 
 RegionPlot[RegionBoundary@reg, AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 250]}
```

[image]

How can one get rid of this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation indicates the following:

> RegionPlot cannot find regions that are just lines or points.

Here is a solution that comes to mind:

```
{RegionPlot[reg, AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 250], 
 RegionPlot[reg, AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 250, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Darker, PlotStyle -> White]}
```

[image]

This also works in the reference question.

```
{RegionPlot[Circle[{0, 0}, 1]], 
 RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y}]]}
```

[image]

```
{RegionPlot[Circle[{0, 0}, 1]], 
 RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}], BoundaryStyle -> Darker, PlotStyle -> White]}
```

[image]